# Sum of product of combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a direct way (i.e. without explicitly doing the sum) of computing:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{min(a,\,b)}{a \choose i}{b \choose i}$$

for a given $a$, $b$.

Is there a closed form way of computing this sum? Can somebody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct way"?. Anyway, the answer is $\binom{a+b}a$, by Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: Here is what [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D0+to+a+of+((a+choose+i)*(b+choose+i))) has to offer

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's exactly what I meant by "direct way", anything that's doesn't involve having to do the entire summation.

Comment: Thanx @LordSharktheUnknown, WaveX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if $a\le b$ then
$$\sum_{i=0}^a\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{i}
=\sum_{i=0}^a\binom{a}{a-i}\binom{b}{i}
=\binom{a+b}a$$
by the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).